# Validation Rule Conflicting with Process builder

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, opportunity, validation, exception

I have this validation rule which locks the field of opportunity when its closedwon/lost. But it is not working as it is conflicting with a flows(which updates closewon/lost dates as today() ) saying This error occurred: **FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION**. These flows and validation rule both uses stage and closewon date fields.

```
AND(
        $User.OpportunityLockOverride__c = FALSE,
        PRIORVALUE( IsClosed ) = True,
        OR(
                ISCHANGED( CloseDate ),
                ISCHANGED( Business_Division__c ),
                ISCHANGED( OwnerId ),
                ISCHANGED( Name ),
                ISCHANGED( AccountId ),
                ISCHANGED( Amount ),
                ISCHANGED( Probability ),
                ISCHANGED( Market__c ),
                ISCHANGED( Opportunity_Countries__c ),
                ISCHANGED( Competitor_Incumbent__c ),
                ISCHANGED( CampaignId ),
                ISCHANGED( NextStep ),
                ISCHANGED( Closed_Reason__c ),
                ISCHANGED( RecordTypeId )
        )
)
```

Comment: The only way for a Flow to be immune from a VR is if the context of the Flow update is known to the VR. Note the flow running user is no different than the user doing normal UX transactions unless the Flow is a Schedule-triggered flow or a Platform_event triggered flow

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this is using following workaround:

- Create a new field on the opportunity called LastModifiedByFlow__c. Can be simple text field
- In the validation rule adjust, that it does **not** fire when this field is changed
- In your flow/process, add an additional update step that sets e.g. the current time step as a value for the field LastModifiedByFlow__c

That means that the flow/process will always change this field and thereby prevent the validation rule from firing. When a user is updating the record via the UI he can't set the field --> Validation Rule fires.

**Note:** This is a) could be exploitet by the users (risk might be pretty low) and b) you need to make sure you implement it in a way that the process really only updates this helper field when needed.